# Multiple Active Directory with 1 application on azure

Tags: spring, azure, azure-active-directory

I have multiple Azure AD with one application in a different azure server; my application is in spring.

My problem is that my application must work with different companies and I don't find how to add on each company, but with one page of login for all companies...

Answer (score 0):

Azure Active Directory applications can support multiple tenants. You need to make sure your application has the setting: `availableToOtherTenants: true`.

From there, you can use the `common` endpoint to dynamically discover which tenant the user is trying to sign into when they type in their user credentials.

This information, and more is in a very apt article titled: [How to sign in any Azure Active Directory (AD) user using the multi-tenant application pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview).

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you that help me . How do you said on spring wittch ad you accept?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand your question. Could you share a screenshot if there is an issue you are running into?

Comment: It was an error of my understanding .i have find how i should do that .thank you